# Post Input Values With KeyBoard

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="surveyForm" method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input type="text"  id="good"  value="0" />
    <input type="text" id="bad" value="1" />    
</form>
```

I want to send value with "g" and "b" keyboard buttons. If "g" button is pressed, form submits with "0" value. How can do this with jquery? I [have searched in site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=submit%20form%20with%20keyboard%20with%20jquery) but I cant find any specific topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 103) { // 'g' keypress
        $("#bad").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#good").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#surveyForm").submit();
    }
    else if (e.which == 98) { // 'b' keypress
        $("#bad").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#good").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#surveyForm").submit();
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could have one input which you change the value of depending on the key pressed and then submit your form. That would be a little more elegant IMO.